# Не работает проверка обьекта struct на null

Tags: c#, null, struct

В классе есть такие поля:

```
   [Serializable]
   public struct MaterialList {
      public Material[] sharedMat_;
      public MaterialList(Material[] m){
                sharedMat_ = m;
      }
   }

    [SerializeField, ReadOnly]
    MaterialList myAnimateMaterial;
```

В одном из методов нужно осуществить проверку: `myAnimateMaterial == null`.
Компилятор ругается на проверку так:

> Operator `==' cannot be applied to operands of type`
>   CubeFreeze.MaterialList' and `null'

Тогда заменяю `MaterialList myAnimateMaterial;` на `MaterialList? myAnimateMaterial;`

Тогда компилятор ругается иначе:

> Type `CubeFreeze.MaterialList?' does not contain a definition for`
>   sharedMat_' and no extension method `sharedMat_' of type`
>   CubeFreeze.MaterialList?' could be found. Are you missing an assembly
>   reference?

Вопрос, почему он не видит sharedMat_? Как сделать так чтобы структуру можно было проверить на null так же как в С++?

И вообще, для чего они запретили проверять структуры на null? В C# обьект структуры никогда не может быть null?

Comment: *В C# обьект структуры никогда не может быть null?* — именно. *Вопрос, почему он не видит sharedMat_?* — обращайтесь к нему через `.Value` или просто через `?.`

Comment: А если его обьявить через "?" то создастся некий класс-обертка, который позволит обращаться к нему через .Value?

Comment: Да, создается `Nullable<T>`, почитайте литературу по этому вопросу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416585/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP так это, мож ответом?

Comment: Ваш `MaterialList` должен быть классом, а не структуртой. См. [Выбор между классом и структурой](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct). К сожалению, перевод на русский очень плох, поэтому, если знаете английский, см. оригинал: [Choosing Between Class and Struct](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Структура является *типом значения*, а переменная типа значения не может иметь значение `null` по определению, поэтому вам придется воспользоваться Nullable-переменной.

Тип `MyStruct?` — это просто алиас для `Nullable<MyStruct>`, а `Nullable<T>`, естественно, не содержит в себе любых случайных полей или свойств (наподобие `sharedMat_`).
Для того, чтобы извлечь из Nullable обернутую им структуру — воспользуйтесь свойством `Value`: `myAnimateMaterial.Value.sharedMat_`;
Также, в `Nullable<T>` определен оператор явного приведения в `T`, этим можно воспользоваться так: `((MaterialList)myAnimateMaterial).sharedMat_`;
Имейте ввиду, что если в переменной типа Nullable лежит значение `null`, то эти 2 способа выбросят исключение, поэтому не забудьте сделать перед этим проверку.
Также, если вас устроит `null`-значение когда сама переменная `myAnimateMaterial` имеет значение `null`, то проще всего воспользоваться null-условным оператором `?.` (C# 6 и выше): `myAnimateMaterial?.sharedMat_`.